# How to use shared preferences in Android?

Tags: java, android

I am implementing toggle button with SQLite in Android. I want to save the Toggle Button values in  Shared Preferences and that shared preferences values store in SQLite. When I run app I got Null Pointer Exception for toggle button.

I don't have idea how to store the boolean value in shared prefs. Here is my Code and Log Cat.

Here is my Toggle ButtonCode

```
toggleButton_Addto_Contacts = (ToggleButton) findViewById(R.id.toggleButton_Add_To_Contacts);

toggleButton_Addto_Contacts.setOnCheckedChangeListener(new OnCheckedChangeListener() {

    @Override
    public void onCheckedChanged(CompoundButton buttonView, boolean isChecked) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub


        if(isChecked)
        {
            System.out.println("Toggle Button Is On");

            SharedPreferences.Editor editor = preferences.edit();
            editor.putBoolean("YES",  true); // value to store
            strBooleanValue=sharedPref.getBoolean("YES",true);
            strToggleVlaue=String.valueOf(strBooleanValue);
            System.out.println("Toggle Button Value Is =" + strToggleVlaue);
            editor.commit();

        }
        else
        {

                System.out.println("Toggle Button Is Off");
                SharedPreferences.Editor editor = preferences.edit();
                editor.putBoolean("NO",  false); // value to store
                strBooleanValue=sharedPref.getBoolean("NO", false);
                strToggleVlaue=String.valueOf(strBooleanValue);
                System.out.println("Toggle Button Value Is =" + strToggleVlaue);
                editor.commit();

        }
    }
});



11-28 15:13:26.054: E/AndroidRuntime(707): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
11-28 15:13:26.054: E/AndroidRuntime(707): java.lang.NullPointerException
11-28 15:13:26.054: E/AndroidRuntime(707):  at com.lead_management_project.New_Lead_Activity5$5.onCheckedChanged(New_Lead_Activity5.java:172)
11-28 15:13:26.054: E/AndroidRuntime(707):  at android.widget.CompoundButton.setChecked(CompoundButton.java:124)
11-28 15:13:26.054: E/AndroidRuntime(707):  at android.widget.ToggleButton.setChecked(ToggleButton.java:69)
11-28 15:13:26.054: E/AndroidRuntime(707):  at android.widget.CompoundButton.toggle(CompoundButton.java:86)
11-28 15:13:26.054: E/AndroidRuntime(707):  at android.widget.CompoundButton.performClick(CompoundButton.java:98)
11-28 15:13:26.054: E/AndroidRuntime(707):  at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:9080)
11-28 15:13:26.054: E/AndroidRuntime(707):  at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:587)
11-28 15:13:26.054: E/AndroidRuntime(707):  at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92)
11-28 15:13:26.054: E/AndroidRuntime(707):  at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:123)
11-28 15:13:26.054: E/AndroidRuntime(707):  at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:3683)
11-28 15:13:26.054: E/AndroidRuntime(707):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
11-28 15:13:26.054: E/AndroidRuntime(707):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:507)
11-28 15:13:26.054: E/AndroidRuntime(707):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:839)
11-28 15:13:26.054: E/AndroidRuntime(707):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:597)
11-28 15:13:26.054: E/AndroidRuntime(707):  at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

Comment: what you have at line 172 in file `New_Lead_Activity5.java`

Comment: At line 172 = strBooleanValue=sharedPref.getBoolean("YES",true);  in file New_Lead_Activity5.java.

Comment: did you initialize your `sharedPref`

Comment: Yah I allready initialize preferences in onCreate() method like this preferences = getPreferences(MODE_PRIVATE);

Comment: yeah you initialized your `preferences`, but what you write at 172 is `strBooleanValue=sharedPref.getBoolean("YES",true);`. Here you accessed `sharedPref` so only i asked for `sharedPref`

Comment: if(isChecked)  At line No 172 =  {SharedPreferences.Editor editor = preferences.edit(); editor.putBoolean("YES",  true);  // value to store
               strBooleanValue=sharedPref.getBoolean("YES",true);
                 strToggleVlaue=String.valueOf(strBooleanValue);
                 editor.commit();

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/42113/discussion-between-tazeenmulani-and-sathishkumar)

Comment: can not get what you are trying to say, are you initialized `sharedPref`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try  to change like below,

```
    if(isChecked)
            {
                System.out.println("Toggle Button Is On");

                SharedPreferences.Editor editor = preferences.edit();
                editor.putBoolean("YES",  true); // value to store
                editor.commit();
                strBooleanValue=preferences.getBoolean("YES",true);
                strToggleVlaue=String.valueOf(strBooleanValue);
                System.out.println("Toggle Button Value Is =" + strToggleVlaue);


            }
 else
        {

                System.out.println("Toggle Button Is Off");
                SharedPreferences.Editor editor = preferences.edit();
                editor.putBoolean("NO",  false); // value to store
                editor.commit();
                strBooleanValue=preferences.getBoolean("NO", false);
                strToggleVlaue=String.valueOf(strBooleanValue);
                System.out.println("Toggle Button Value Is =" + strToggleVlaue);


        }
```

Answer (score 0):

you are not initializing `preferences` or `sharedPref` anywhere in your code and that's y you are getting `NullPointerException`

Also there is something not right in your following piece of code:-

```
editor.putBoolean("YES",  true); // value to store
strBooleanValue=sharedPref.getBoolean("YES",true);
```

You must first call `commit()` and then should try to access the value that you've put in the preferences.

Comment: I allready initialize preferences in onCreate() method like this preferences = getPreferences(MODE_PRIVATE);

Answer (score 0):

please see below answer

```
   creating sharedpreferences
    SharedPreferences pref = getApplicationContext().getSharedPreferences("MyPref", 0); // 0 - for private mode
    Editor editor = pref.edit();

    Storevalues
    editor.putBoolean("key_name", true); // Storing boolean - true/false
    editor.putString("key_name", "string value"); // Storing string
    editor.putInt("key_name", "int value"); // Storing integer
    editor.putFloat("key_name", "float value"); // Storing float
    editor.putLong("key_name", "long value"); // Storing long

   editor.commit(); // commit changes

  retrive from shared preference

    SharedPreferences pref = getApplicationContext().getSharedPreferences("MyPref", 0); // 0 - for private mode
   pref.getString("key_name", null); // getting String
   pref.getInt("key_name", null); // getting Integer
   pref.getFloat("key_name", null); // getting Float
   pref.getLong("key_name", null); // getting Long
  pref.getBoolean("key_name", null); // getting boolean
```

Answer (score 0):

After setContentView Just call loadSavedPreferences()

```
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.setting);
         loadSavedPreferences();
          //remaining code
 }
```

And call savePreferences(Boolean toggle) in onCheckedChanged

```
   public void onCheckedChanged(CompoundButton buttonView, boolean isChecked) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
      savePreferences(Boolean toggle);
  if(isChecked)
    {
        System.out.println("Toggle Button Is On");
        System.out.println("Toggle Button Value Is =" + strToggleVlaue);


    }
    else
    {

            System.out.println("Toggle Button Is Off");
            System.out.println("Toggle Button Value Is =" + strToggleVlaue);


    }
}
 });


private void loadSavedPreferences() {
            SharedPreferences sharedPreferences =PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(this);
            strToggleVlaue==getBoolean("Checked_State",true);
        }

  private void savePreferences(Boolean toggle) {

            SharedPreferences sharedPreferences  PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(this);
            Editor editor = sharedPreferences.edit();
            editor.putBoolean("Checked_State",toggle);
             editor.commit();

        }
```

**Note:** write a separate method  for shared preference to load and save so that in future in you want to save any another value you can easily modify these functions.